# Xamarin.forms- Trouble with bottom shadow toolbar ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, navigation, uinavigationbar

I'm workin' on an Xamarin.forms app chat and I'm havin' some troubles with the NavigationBar. The problem resides on the shadow of toolbar , i want it desappear.

It was already working with the code below but now it stopped working.

**Image**
[!enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Lkn.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Lkn.png)

**Code**
***AppDelegate***

```
        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags(new string[] { "CarouselView_Experimental", "IndicatorView_Experimental" });
        ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
        KeyboardOverlapRenderer.Init();
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App(null, null, null));
        OneSignal.Current.StartInit("8bf7b19d-fb86-4ffb-a17e-5998f6756883").HandleNotificationOpened(App.HandleNotificationOpened).EndInit();

        UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
        UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 255, 255);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that not working , there is another **solution** to implement that by customing a `NavigationPage`.

Create a **CustomNavigationPage** :

```
public class CustomNavigationPage : NavigationPage
{
    public CustomNavigationPage(Page root) : base(root)
    {
    }
}
```

In **App.xaml.cs** :

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CustomNavigationPage navigationPage = new CustomNavigationPage(new MainPage());
    MainPage = navigationPage;
}
```

Then in iOS solution , you can create the **CustomNavigationRenderer** to modify navigation bar :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomNavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationRenderer))]
namespace AppFrameRenderer.iOS
{
    public class CustomNavigationRenderer: NavigationRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
        }
    }
}
```

The effect as expected :

[image]

Comment: Did not work. Could it be some configuration that is preventing rendering?

Comment: @RafaVieira That will be possible . Could you share the App.xaml.cs code , I will check that . Or you can create a new sample project to test my shared solution and check whether it works first .

Comment: It works on a new project, I will now compare and try to find out what may be happening.

Comment: @RafaVieira That's great ! If finding remember to share here :-）